# DMS (Doc Management System) Discussion and advice

Tags: jakarta-ee, liferay, alfresco, dms, nuxeo

I'm a student and I have a project what is creating a **Document Management System** with JEE ,I'm making a first study and comparison between the DMS in the market ( Nuxeo,LifeRay,Alfresco,M-files  ...) my questions are :
      1 : what is the best DMS to focus on it ?
      2 : I'm using JEE ,which is the architecture should use MVC or MVVM or others ?
      3 : What's the best JEE frameworks that I should use (persistence ,presentation ...) ?
any suggestion will be highly appreciated and Thank you very much ;)

Comment: If you are lookiing for something open source , i will suggest to go with Liferay. It has a readymade document and media portlet shipped in with the vanilla version.

Comment: **Maverick thx** and , what about the architecture that I should ,and frameworks ?

Comment: By the way, Alfresco is also Open Source, and it was conceived as a a powerful Content Managemente System from the beginning. For Liferay, DMS/CMS was a recent addition.

Answer (score 2):

First of all: your question is too generic.

You'll to to define DMS. From my point of view Alfresco is an DMS, Liferay is not - it has some basic DMS features...

1. Alfresco
2. depends on your requirements - I would prefer to offer a robust & well-designed REST API & implement the whole front-end using a SPA-Framework like ember, angular ...
3. depends on your requirements